# Correct path notation to access custom module from another custom module in node.js

Tags: node.js, class, path, require, node-modules

I have some custom class modules in my node.js project. Is it possible to access a custom module from another custom module?  If so, what path notation can I use? I can't seem to come up with one that doesn't produce the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'someModules/DB'`. I can export and `require('./someModules/DB')` fine from my root index.js script.  But it doesn't work from `someModules/Table`.  Here's my directory structure:

```
project root
  -index.js
  -someModules
    --DB
      ---index.js
    --Table
      ---index.js
```

I want to access DB/index.js from Table/index.js.  I tried obvious things like:

`const DB = require("/someModules/DB");`

`const DB = require("./someModules/DB");`

`const DB = require("../someModules/DB");`

`const DB = require("someModules/DB");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  You dont need to and arent going higher up them someModules

```
  const DB = require("../DB");
```